# How to exclude folder that is out of root directory in eslint?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint, git-submodules

That is the project structure I have:

```
-lib (git submodule with js library)
-A (vue.js+typesript+eslint app that uses lib)
-B (other module with express app)
```

While running `A` app I'm facing errors with eslint at `lib`:

```
Error: Failed to load config "airbnb" to extend from.
```

How can I exclude `lib` from eslint processing at `A` app?

I tried to add `.eslintignore` to root directory and `A` directory. Also tried to add `ignorePatterns` to `A` eslint configs. Nothing helped.

Appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: This sounds like a config issue. Your ESLint is extending `airbnb`, which it can't find. Can you link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue by configuring `.eslintignore` correctly. Just added the following line:

```
../lib/*
```